# Exclude holidays between two selected dates in pyhton odoo

Tags: python, odoo

How can I calculate total hours between two dates. here I have to select the start date and end date. and every day an employee works 8 hours per day.  I calculate the total hours between these two dates. For example if I select two dates from: 11/21/2022 and date to:11/22/2022. These two dates total hours are 16 hours. and date need to count without holiday how can I do that. Please help me. Here I want to exclude holidays between the total days.please help me

```
@api.depends("start_date", "date_deadline")
def _compute_hours(self):
    if self.start_date and self.date_deadline:
        t1 = datetime.strptime(str(self.start_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
        print(t1)
        t2 = datetime.strptime(str(self.date_deadline), '%Y-%m-%d')
        print('=================================T2')
        print(t2)
        t3 = t2 - t1
        # count = sum(1 for day in t3 if day.weekday() < 5)
        # print(count)
        print('=================================T3')
        print(t3)
        print('=================================')
        seconds = t3.total_seconds() / 3
        diff_in_hours = seconds / 3600
        print('Difference between two datetimes in hours:')
        print(diff_in_hours)
        self.total_hours = diff_in_hours
```

I am trying to exclude holidays from total days

Comment: holiday = sat sun only?

Comment: friday and saterday

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use weekday function to find the weekday for that day. Then compare it with holidays.

```py
In  [1]: from datetime import date, timedelta 
    ...:  
    ...: start_date = date(2019, 1, 1) 
    ...: end_date = date(2020, 1, 1) 
    ...: delta = timedelta(days=1) 
    ...: count = 0 
    ...: while start_date <= end_date: 
    ...:     print(start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) 
    ...:     start_date += delta 
    ...:     if start_date.weekday() in [5,6]: # 5 is friday, 6 is sat
    ...:         print('holiday') 
    ...:         count += 1 
    ...: print("total holidays", count)
```

Now you have holidays count, so you can subtract it.

i.e

total holidays 104

```
total_hours - (count * 8) # count is number, 8 is working hours
```

Comment: Here this code i define the holidays but how can I exclude these holidays from total days.
Here this code total days retrieved from t3

Comment: you can count total days as well and total_days - count is the difference

Comment: Brother If I exclude a number of date as holiday then how can I do that

Comment: This is what is happening here.

Comment: here weekly two days count as holidays its ok but I want to exclude other holidays that means my countries holidays by using this: for date in holidays.BD(years=[2022, 2023, 2024, 2025]): print(date) i have get all the holidays in my country but how can I exclude these dates from my selected dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use the company default working hours to [compute the number of work](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/resource/models/resource.py#L637) hours between two datetimes. The method is taking into account the global leaves.

You can find an example in [hr_leave](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/hr_holidays/models/hr_leave.py#L678) module:

```
 hours = self.env.company.resource_calendar_id.get_work_hours_count(date_from, date_to)
```